# Unique number counter function?

Tags: javascript

This undoubtedly already exists but I can't find it anywhere after 20 min of looking.

All I want is a function that counts up so the first time you call uniqueNum() it returns 0, then 1, then 2 etc.

```
function uniqueNum(){
    if (typeof x !== 'number') {
        var x = 0;
    } else {
        x++;
    }
    return x
}
```

I don't want any globals or vars outside of the function hopefully.

What I've got always returns 0;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A closure can do that:

```
var uniqueNum = (function(){
    var num = 0;
    return function(){
        return num++;
    }
}());
uniqueNum(); // 0
uniqueNum(); // 1
```

A "static" variable works too, as suggested in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888413/825789) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888431/825789).

Comment: You might find 'Javascript the good parts' by Douglas Crockford a good read for this kind tip.

Comment: @DarrenWhite I remember the book has an example of that, but I don't remember if Crockford uses a closure or a constructor property. I believe it's the latter, but I don't have the book with me right now to check. Do you know which one the book uses?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a "static" variable like this:

```
function uniqueNum() {
    return uniqueNum.counter = (uniqueNum.counter || 0)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will use the function itself for storing the counter:

```
function uniqueNum() {
    if (uniqueNum.x == null) {
        uniqueNum.x = 0;
    } else {
        uniqueNum.x++;
    }

    return uniqueNum.x;
}

console.log(uniqueNum()); // 0
console.log(uniqueNum()); // 1
console.log(uniqueNum.x); // 1
```

Comment: I believe that checking `uniqueNum.x == null` is a bit misleading (although it works), because the first time `uniqueNum.x` will return `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: I know it works, what I mean is that you're checking for `null` or `undefined`, but `uniqueNum.x` will *never* be `null`. And sorry for the nitpick!